# Finding homotopy

Tags: algebraic-topology

Find a homotopy F from f to g where $f:[0,1] \rightarrow S^1, f(t)=e^{i \pi t}$ and $g:[0,1] \rightarrow S^1, g(t)=e^{-i \pi t}$.

My attempt: Let $F: [0,1] \times [0,1] \rightarrow S^1$  where $(s,t) \rightarrow \dfrac{(1-t)e^{i \pi s}+t e^{-i \pi s}}{|(1-t)e^{i \pi s}+t e^{-i \pi s}|}$.

The above seems to satisfy the properties that a homotopy should have but is not well defined for $s=t=1/2$.

Can a change make this idea work?

Comment: Can you show both maps are homotopic to constants?

Comment: @JasonDeVito I think so, using the maps $(s,t) \rightarrow e^{i \pi (1-t)s}$ and $(s,t) \rightarrow e^{-i \pi (1-t)s}$. Then if i haven't made a mistake they are both homotopic to the constant map (1,0)

Comment: I think that works.  Have you already shown the relation "homotopic" is an equivalence relation?

Comment: @JasonDeVito: I wonder why two circles of opposite directions are not homotopic but the above two maps (that represent that loops) are homotopic?

Comment: @C.F.G It is not required that the homotopy is a homotopy of paths (which keeps the endpoints fixed).

Comment: @PaulFrost: So they are completely unrelated? (path-homotopy and homotopic functions)

Comment: @C.F.G Path homotopy implies (free) homotopy. The converse is wrong. The problem is that a free homotopy in general ist not stationary on $\{0,1\} \subset [0,1]$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Yes, I kow that. So by the combination of the two maps I defined above I get the homotopy I wanted .